# How to resolve "Unresolved variable or type data" warnings when using EJS?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm using **EJS** as Template engine. Everything looks like working fine, but I have these weak **"Unresolved variable or type data"** warnings in IntelliJ. How to get rid of these warnings? Is anything wrong with the code?

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/static', express.static('static'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});

app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
  var userData = {
    id: req.params.id,
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Peterson',
    age: 23,
    active: true,
    interests: ['Design', 'Web', 'Acting']
  };
  res.render('profile', { data: userData });
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/404.html`);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}`);
```

**views/profile.ejs**:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>My Profile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>My Profile Template</h2>
      <p>ID: <%=data.id%></p>
      <p>Name: <%=data.firstName%> <%=data.lastName%></p>
      <p>Age: <%=data.age%> years</p>
      <p>Active: <%=data.active%></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an ejs file plugin for your editor? It seems your editor thinks that variable in undefined. Does your editor think that is an HTML file?

Comment: Yes, EJS plugin is installed, also removed and re-installed again.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @JBis nothing till now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, by adding spaces between `%=%`.

```
<p>Name: <%= data.firstName %> <%= data.lastName %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to export the `data` object somewhere in your code.

Try to add `module.exports = { data: {}; }` to the end of your `app.js` file.

To make autocomplete work correctly, you should either export a real object (`userData`) instead of an empty one, or use TypeScript.